# How to add email field to Stripe checkout for one-time payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am selling a product on my website. I have Stripe setup and have been accepting orders. I added a email field, however it is not saving to Stripe.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, if someone could offer some help. The email field is towards the bottom of the code.

popup_html.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="model_stripe" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Credit Card Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="submit_card_info"></div>
                <form class="form-horizontal te-ajax-form" id="upgrade_form"  action="upgrade/payment" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="">Card Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input class="form-control required" name="cardnumber" id="cardnumber" type="text" placeholder="Card Number" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="">CVC</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input class="form-control required" name="cvc" id="cvc" type="text" placeholder="CVC" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="">Expiration</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <select id="expMonth" style="width:100%;padding:5px;">
                                        <?php
                                        $year = date('Y');
                                        for ($i=1; $i < 13; $i++) { 
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <select id="expYear" name="year" style="width:100%;padding:5px;">
                                        <?php
                                        $year = date('Y');
                                        for ($i=1; $i < 21; $i++) { 
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $year+$i ?>"><?php echo $year+$i ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="">E-mail Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input class="form-control required" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Your E-mail Address" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form id="upgrade_form_token" class="te-ajax-form" action="inc/stripe_charge.php">
```

Stripe_handler.php:

```
<?php
require_once ('stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
define('PRICE',9.99);
$stripe = array(
    'secret_key'      => ' sk_test_665545656565656 ',
    'publishable_key' => 'pk_test_35845754785784578'
);
Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>");
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#model_stripe .extra_items input').change(function(){
            if( jQuery(this).attr('name')=='info[addon3]' ){
                if(  jQuery(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    jQuery('#saNotes').show();
                } else {
                    jQuery('#saNotes').hide();
                }
            }
            var extra_for_stripe = 0;
            jQuery('#model_stripe .extra_items input:checked').each(function(){
                extra_for_stripe += Number(jQuery(this).val());
            });

            var  notes = false;
            var total_charges = extra_for_stripe+(<?php echo PRICE ?>);
            jQuery('#upgrade_form_token').find('[name="amount"]').val(total_charges);
            jQuery('#model_stripe .total_charges').text('$'+total_charges)
        });

        jQuery("#proceed_stripe").click(function(event) {
            jQuery('#submit_card_info .payment-message').remove();
            var card_no = jQuery('#cardnumber').val();
            var cvc = jQuery('#cvc').val();
            if(card_no.length==0){
                var errorHTML = '<div class="payment-message alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button ><p>Card Number is required.</p></div>';
                jQuery("#submit_card_info").prepend(errorHTML);
                return false;
            }
            if(cvc.length==0){
                var errorHTML = '<div class="payment-message alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button ><p>CVS is required.</p></div>';
                jQuery("#submit_card_info").prepend(errorHTML);
                return false;
            }
            // jQuery('#model_stripe .modal-footer button ').attr('disabled',true);
            Stripe.createToken({
                number: card_no,
                cvc: cvc,
                exp_month: jQuery('#expMonth').val(),
                exp_year: jQuery('#expYear').val(),
            }, stripeResponseHandler);
            return false; // submit from callback
        });
    });
    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
            jQuery('#upgrade_button').removeAttr("disabled");
            // show the errors on the form
            var errorHTML = '<div class="payment-message alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button ><p>'+response.error.message+'</p></div>';
            jQuery("#submit_card_info").prepend(errorHTML);
        }
         else {
            var form = jQuery("#proceed_stripe");
            // token contains id, last4, and card type
            var token = response['id'];
            // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            jQuery('#upgrade_form_token input[name="stripeToken"]').val(token);
            jQuery('#footer-form input[type="text"], #footer-form select').each(function(){
                var h = '<input value="'+jQuery(this).val()+'" name="info['+jQuery(this).attr('name')+']" type="hidden">';
                jQuery('#upgrade_form_token').append(h);
            });
            jQuery('#upgrade_form_token').submit();
        }

    }

    function upgrade_form_token_success(form,resp){
        jQuery('#submit_card_info .payment-message').remove();
        if( resp.type=='success'){
            var h = '<div style="display: block;font-size: 16px;padding-bottom: 10px;font-weight: bold;">Thanks for buying. <a href="index.php" title="products">Buy More</a></div>';
            jQuery("#model_stripe .modal-body").html(h);
            jQuery("#model_stripe .modal-footer").remove();
            jQuery("#model_stripe .modal-backdrop").css({
                'opacity':1,
                'background-color':'#fff',
            });
        } else {   
            jQuery("#submit_card_info").append(bs_alert('danger',resp.msg ) );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is just a form. It's useless to study form without it's handler.

Comment: If I were you, I would change your code in total unless you are 100% sure that your server is bulletproof secure. Don't let credit card data touch your server, remove all the name fields in your form except for stuff like email, and send the data to stripe before your server handles it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stripe has some good documentation on converting an existing form to a Stripe form @ https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/switching.

(1) Note that you remove the the name attribute from all sensitive input fields ( as noted by [michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3993662/michael) above)  Unless you are running a PCI compliant server, this is critical.

(2) When you parse your form and try and finally try and charge the card, you want to pass in the email address as receipt_email:customer@email.com (see https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge)

Hope this helps!